# Erlang foreach gives error: syntax error before: ')'

Tags: erlang

Im doing a parallell sodukusolver but right now the program gives me an error. Im trying to spawn processes in parallel that test different possible solutions. Part of the code is below.

```
par_solve_refined(M) ->
  case solved(M) of
    true ->
      M;
    false ->
      %% split into chunks to control granularity
      Chunks = partition(2, guesses(M)),
      Parent = self(),
      %% here below the program gives an error: "syntax error before: ')'"
      foreach(fun(I) -> spawn(fun() -> Parent ! solve_one(I) end) end, Chunks),
      receive
        Solution -> Solution
      end
  end.        

partition(_, []) ->
   [];
partition(N, L) ->
   try case lists:split(N, L) of
        {Fst, Snd} -> [Fst|partition(N, Snd)]
       end
   catch
     error:badarg -> [L]
end.
```

Comment: "gives me an error" isn't a proper description. Please specify what error is printed and where.

Comment: I think you need a '.' after the `end` on the previous line.

Comment: Seems parenthesis after `spawn(` isn't closed.

Comment: @Netch Allright thanks, but that was not all...

Comment: foreach(fun(I) -> spawn(fun() -> Parent ! solve_one(I) end), Chunks), -- I tried to place parentheses according to the common sense and logic.

Comment: @Netch, your completely right. But it still gives me this mysterious error. Maybe it has to do with the receive --- end afterwards?

Comment: The first `fun` shall also be closed with corresponding `end`.

Comment: @Netch, thanks for your patience, it was my fault not understanding to read all the involved functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
lists:foreach(fun(I) -> spawn(fun() -> Parent ! solve_one(I) end) end, Chunks)
```

Comment: what is the problem? i run this code, everything is ok.

Comment: I now saw that it was the call to solve_one that was not working. Thank you.

Comment: Could you share your code with me? I want learn about suku, i think your idea is very good, using a lot of process to check every result.

Comment: Give me you email and I send you a copy of the code. I cant share it on internet since Im refining somebody elses sequential code. And this is a schoolassigment.

Answer (score 0):

lists:foreach(Function, List) is probably the function you need.